# Can any body tell me how I'll able to send email by using phpmailer in wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, phpmailer

I have tired many solutions and posted code but I didn't get any response please help me. My function doesn't even give an error.

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'New_Mail');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function New_Mail($phpmailer){

print_r($phpmailer);

die();

}
```

Comment: Are you using a PHPMailer Plugin?

Comment: Thanks for helping here is the function that I'm using right now `add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'new_email' );
function new_email( $phpmailer ) {

echo "Here it is";
die();

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();     
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // Force it to use Username and Password to authenticate
    $phpmailer->Port = 25;
    $phpmailer->Username = 'yourusername';
    $phpmailer->Password = 'yourpassword';

}

`  It doesn't show any error nor echo something.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a plugin like "[Easy SMTP](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/)" and use normally [wp-mail functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/). Its rather than reinventing the wheel.